# How do I deploy a MimosaJS site to Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

How do I deploy a [MimosaJS](http://mimosajs.com/index.html) site to [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/)? Is there any guides out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mimosa author here.  It just so happens I wrote a short guide on doing just that thing on the website a few weeks ago.

http://mimosajs.com/about.html#Heroku

The key is the use of mimosa-web-package.

If you have any questions hit me up here, the google group or on twitter.  Hope it works out for ya!

Comment: Wow, I'm not sure how I missed that. Thanks!